# Setting priority -20 to process in Linux with c++

Tags: c++, linux

In linux priority value is in range(-20,19). I want to archive file with zip and set priority -20 to this process. But every time when I check, it shows priority value=0.

So I try to start this command as root, but I get the same result.  Every time when I try to set priority below 0 it becomes 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int prio;
    cout << "Enter priority: ";
    cin >> prio;

    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, prio);

    string path;
    cout << "Enter file path: ";
    cin >> path;

    string command = "sudo -S zip -j " + path + ".zip " + path;
    system(command.c_str());

    cout<<"Current priority: "<<getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system()` with `sudo` and absolutely no shell escaping? This code is **super dangerous**. This could be toy code, but it's a reckless habit to get into.

Comment: Hint: `fork`, `execvp()` (or equivalent) and manage your child process priority.

Comment: I want to change priority to -20. How I can do this with creating child process or current process image?

Comment: The "priority" is the same as the "nice" level. The lower values are actually the *higher* priority (because it's the same as the nice level), and you need extra privileges to raise the priority (lower the nice level) of a process. I suggest you add some error checking, to make sure that e.g. `setpriority` doesn't fail. And if it does, then check `errno` to see what error you get.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I create a child process to launch a command without creating a child process (`fork()`), or launching a command (`execvp()`)?"